# Do private members add any performance benefit?

Tags: objective-c, performance, llvm

I know that (at least for some JIT-ed languages like Java) that declaring member variables private allow certain compiler optimizations to take place. I realize that this may not be universally true, but I've seen this in practice particularly when it comes to embedded JIT compilers for Java. My question is, is there any compile-time benefit (or run time benefit) that private members can confer in Objective-C LLVM?

I'm asking for my own edification, so please no "don't prematurely optimize" comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Private members" as in @private ivars? If so then no, the compiler can't do anything as far as optimizing those, its purely a marker to specify the contract of the ivar.